# Convert plain string to html in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**How can I convert this plain text to HTML in reactjs?

```
**Text:** 

The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

**It automatically converts like this:**

```
<p>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
```

Comment: You mean just converting the plain text to `p` tags ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can split the string line by line, here's an example:

```
<div>
  {`The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit`
    .split("\n")
    .map((line) => (
      <p style={{ backgroundColor: "#D8DC6A" }}>{line}</p>
    ))}
</div>
```

You can see the results in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-architecture-pqtu4?file=/src/App.js:71-361)

Comment: Yeah, your code is working properly. But want to save this data in a variable. 

Like this: <p>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>

Answer (score 0):

You can store the needed strings in a state or simple variables or even can pass from props.

Then on rendering, you can map them as html elements.

**code**

```
const DemoComponent = props => {
  const strings = ['The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s',
                   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit]
  return (
  <div>
    {strings.map( element => <p> {element}</p>)}
  </div>);

}

export default DemoComponent;
```

**Note** - i have not run this code, but the logic would be same