# Convert Text Strings to Rendered HTML in React, Similar to wordhtml.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a small React project where I have two boxes: one for input and another for output. I want the input text to be displayed as rendered HTML in the output box. Essentially, I'm looking for the reverse of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's not giving me the desired result:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./InputOutput.css";

const InputOutput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [outputValue, setOutputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const paragraphs = inputValue.split("\n").map((p) => p.trim());
    const htmlParagraphs = paragraphs.map((p) => {
      if (!p) return "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
      return `<p>${p.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;")}</p>`;
    });
    setOutputValue(htmlParagraphs.join(""));
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="input-box">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <textarea
          placeholder="Type here"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="output-box">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <div>{outputValue}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputOutput;
```

**Input:**

```
Hello all, my name is Alex

This is one empty lane

These are 2 empty lanes
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<p>Hello all, my name is Alex</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>This is one empty lane</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>These are 2 empty lanes</p>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Showed on the question

Should be similar to [Convert plain string to html in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513715/convert-plain-string-to-html-in-react)

Comment: What does the current output look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: Why is htmlParagraphs an array of strings and not an array of react "p" elements?

Comment: Is this so you can see newlines etc, if so you could just set the `div` to render with a style of `white-space: pre`..

Answer (score 1):

you can define outputValue as component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const InputOutput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [outputValue, setOutputValue] = useState(<></>);

  useEffect(() => {
    const paragraphs = inputValue.split("\n").map((p) => p.trim());
    const htmlParagraphs = <>
    {
       paragraphs.map((p) => {
        if (!p) return <p>&nbsp;</p>;
        return <p>{p}</p>;
      })
    }
    </>
   
    setOutputValue(htmlParagraphs);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="input-box">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <textarea
          placeholder="Type here"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="output-box">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <div>{outputValue}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, with map operator.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [outputValue, setOutputValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const paragraphs = inputValue.split('\n').map((p) => p.trim());
    const htmlParagraphs = paragraphs;
    setOutputValue(htmlParagraphs);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="input-box">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <textarea
          placeholder="Type here"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="output-box">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        {outputValue &&
          outputValue.map((element) => (element ? <p> {element}</p> : <br />))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ck2g6z?file=src%2FApp.js)